# Jenkins can't find step definition of capybara

Tags: jenkins, capybara, undefined

I have installed Jenkins on windows server and setup test environment in the same server.

I have a job for running the cmd command as following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;
cucumber C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\web-automation\features --tag @auth
```

when I run the same command via cmd on the server it works fine but Jenkins gives an error about undefined steps as following:

```
6 scenarios (6 undefined)
34 steps (34 undefined)
0m0.070s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given(/^I login to to system as "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

. . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing when you run via CMD you are in cucumber's project folder... In my understanding your problem is telling where cucumber should find and run the features, but if your terminal is not in that folder structure, cucumber won't know how to find your step definitions... There is probably 2 ways of solving the problem:

In Jenkins, prior to running the cucumber command, navigate to:

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\web-automation
```

Then run:

```
cucumber features --tag @auth
```

or run the following command without navigating to cucumber test suite:

```
cucumber C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\web-automation\features -r C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\web-automation\features --tag @auth
```